# Is it possible in SQL Server to view multiple databases with one login?

Tags: sql-server

My first question post: I have SQL Server 2017 CU14 dev edition running at Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Let's say I have 3 databases `masterdb, child1, child2` and with `sa` login I can see all 3 databases.

Is it possible, for example, to create a login `mike` to view only `child1` and `child2` databases, and not showing `masterdb`?

I already tried other methods, but resulting only in 1 on 1 relation, 1 login view 1 db (not showing others 2 db)

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: You have the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, however, that does what it says; you can either see any or none. You can't hide specific objects from a login in the `sys.databases` object; it's all or the system databases.

Comment: hi Larnu, so basically you are saying that it is not possible for that scenario?

Comment: No, don't believe so. Just because a login can see a database exists doesn't mean they have access to it though.

Comment: true, but my condition require to hide some of the dbs, and only show relevant dbs to a specific user (login)

Comment: `VIEW ANY DATABASE` is a login permission, your above comment doesn't change my response.

Comment: can you elaborate more? do you mean like= deny view any database to [login]

Comment: `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [YourLogin];` would deny the login from seeing any databases other than `master` and `tempdb`. Also, correction, they'll be able to see databases they own.

Comment: okay, after that is it use= ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname TO [login] ?
if i run that syntax twice, with dbname = chlid1 and child2, other login with view to child2 will not see child2 anymore

Answer (score 0):

The `VIEW ANY DATABASE` might be what you are after *if* the login has a user that owns the database in question. Take the below example:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN Test WITH PASSWORD = '123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER Test;

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO Test;
GO

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Test';
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases;

REVERT;
GO
DROP DATABASE test;
DROP LOGIN TestDB;
```

Notice that in the first `SELECT`, only `tempdb` and `master` are shown. After the second, `TestDB` also shows as the User `Test` (mapepd to the Login `Test`) owns the database `TestDB`.

Note that a `user` being part of the `db_owner` role doesn't let them see the database (or any other role):

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN Test WITH PASSWORD = '123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER Test;

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO Test;
GO
CREATE DATABASE SampleDB;
GO
USE SampleDB;
GO
CREATE USER Test FOR LOGIN Test;
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER Test;
GO
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE ExampleDB;
GO
USE ExampleDB;
GO
CREATE USER Test FOR LOGIN Test;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER Test;
GO
USE master;
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Test';
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases;

REVERT;
GO
DROP DATABASE TestDB;
DROP DATABASE SampleDB;
DROP DATABASE ExampleDB;
DROP LOGIN Test;
```

Neither `SampleDB` or `ExampleDB` ever show up in the `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Many thanks Larnu, it works !!

I used the first query, and add 

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB1;
GO

that for create 2 db for login test

and when login as Test, that user can see TestDB and TestDB1, and can not see others DBs

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Hi Larnu, out of curiosity, above scenario is for 1 login view multiple DBs. Now i wonder if is it possible for 1 DB can be seen at multiple login (multiple user)

login= Test can see testDB and testDB1
login= Tester can see testDB and testDB2

in this case, testDB could be seen by login Test and Tester

Comment: As I said in my answer, @MichaelSanjaya, a login with `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE` can **only** see databases they own, `tempdb` and `master`. Nothing else.